# Defining Windows phone specific CSS

Tags: html, css, windows-phone

I am developing a mobile web application in HTML,I have used -ve margin in a particular div.
But its not getting reflected in windows phone.
I just want to know is there any other way to define specific css for windows phone?

Please help me in this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782871/css-to-target-windows-phone-7

Comment: I would say, use [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/). At a certain size of the screen you can assume it is a mobile devive.

Comment: I don't know why you have used `-ve` margin, May be there's a better solution if you put some code.

Answer (score 1):

WP7 or 8?

```
<!--[if IEMobile]> 
   Displayed only on Internet Explorer Mobile on Windows Phone 7 (don't know what about WP8)
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: IE10/IE11 will ignore conditional comments.