# CSS media query to target Windows Phone Nokia Lumia

Tags: html, css, mobile, windows-phone-8, less

I am using below LESS to target mobile phones and all other devices are working, but Window phone position: relative breaks the whole UI.

```
li {
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      position: relative;
      top: 4px;
      zoom: 0.5;
      width: 46px;
  }
}
```

How can I target only windows phone specifically using media queries.

I have been through below solutions, but they are using conditional CSS tag and my project uses LESS.

[CSS to target Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782871/css-to-target-windows-phone-7)

And below solution targets dpi, that probably might change in future devices. Hence this does not solve my problem.

[@media query to target hi-res Windows Phone 8+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421493/media-query-to-target-hi-res-windows-phone-8)

Comment: Maybe your code is incorrect and doesn't work on WinPhone? Fix problem with position: relative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Zitscher for your inputs.
But I found a hack that worked for me
http://blog.simian.co/en/tips/internet-explorer-10-mobile-css-hacks-windows-phone/
(this may be helpful to someone)

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active) and (max-width: 30em),
(-ms-high-contrast: none) and (max-width: 30em) {
       width: 130px !important;
       padding-left:18px !important;
}
```

This is what I was looking for.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't rely solely on media queries when applying styles for a certain device. Try using the check library is.js (http://is.js.org/#windowsPhone) like in this example:

```
if(is.windowsPhone()) {
    $('body').addClass('is-windows-phone')
}
```

Now in your styles you could do something like this:

```
body.is-windows-phone ul#fancyWindowsPhoneList li {
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
    zoom: 0.5;
    width: 46px;
}
```

Hope this helps!